# How to set legend in PieChart using GoogleChartSharp?

Tags: c#, google-visualization, pie-chart

What I am trying to do is creating an image of PieChart using `GoogleChartSharp` assembly. Now the problem is that `PieChart` class does not support the `pieChart.SetLegend()` method which we can achieve easily when we generate pie chart using javascript.

This is what I am getting as an image:
[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

This is what we see in code if we use `pieChart.SetLegend()`.

[image: c]

Can anyone please tell me is there any way to generate legend using `PieChart` class?